# Bucle for con distintos resultados

Tags: javascript

Actualmente tengo 3 botones en un html dentro de un div. Dichos botones los selecciono con un `var ff = f0.querySelectorAll("button")` (f0 hace referencia al div donde están los botones).

Puedo acceder a los 3 botones poniendo ff[0,1,2].

El problema viene cuando, a la hora de agregar funcionalidad a los botones:

```
      var tem = document.querySelectorAll("template");

        this.id=id;

      let f0 = document.createElement('div');
      f0.innerHTML = tem[3].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(f0);

      this.contentForm = f0.querySelector(".content-form");

      var ff = f0.querySelectorAll("button");

      for(let i = 0; i < ff.length; i++){
         f0.querySelector(ff[i]).addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log('hola');
         })
      }
   }
```

En el ultimo `bucle for`, no puedo poner un querySelector del `ff[i]`, a pesar de estar declarado. Imagino que es porque no sigue la estructura correcta. Me gustaría saber cómo se hace.

A parte de eso, una vez esté solucionado de cómo nombrar a los 3 botones en un simple bucle, ¿cómo podría asignar una función distinta a cada botón? Es decir:

En el ejemplo los 3 botones, una vez se consiga seleccionar a los 3, una vez hecho clic, TODOS imprimen por consola un "hola". Me gustaría que uno dijera hola, otro adios, y otro bienvenido.

**

### [EDIT]

**

Tratando de hacer la asignación de funcionalidades en el bucle for, me topo con que no estoy asignando nada realmente:

```
let f0 = document.createElement('div');
      f0.innerHTML = tem[3].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(f0);

      this.contentForm = f0.querySelector(".content-form");

      var ff = f0.querySelectorAll("button");
      console.log(ff);

      for(let i = 0; i < ff.length; i++){
         if(ff[0].clicked == true){
            console.log('hola');
         }
      }
```

Según la docu, verificar si un botón ha sido clicado es así mediante javascript, sin necesidad de un addEventListener, dentro de un if...else

### **[EDIT 2]**

Ahora me funciona el clicker, PERO, lo repite TRES veces...

```
for(let i = 0; i < ff.length; i++){
         if(ff[0].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            console.log('hola');
         }));
      }
```

Comment: porque accedes asi? => `f0.querySelector(ff[i])`, si tu variable `ff`, ya tiene los elementos, deberías simplemente realizar un `ff[i]`; ahora para asignar a cada botón una función diferente, podrías controlar dicha asignación mediante el índice de cada elemento

Comment: Porque soy idiota y no me había dado ni cuenta XD
Muchas gracias

Comment: Jejeje, si resuelves lo de la asignación de funciones, te invito a que compartas tu solución con la comunidad :D

Comment: Creo que si llego a resolver eso, me dan un puesto fijo en la empresa donde estoy de prácticas mas bien XD
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: No es tan difícil, dentro del for ya puedes acceder a cada elemento mediante su índice por lo que deberías realizar condiciones if solamente. Por ejemplo, si indice es igual a 0, se le asigna hola, y así... ;)

Comment: Ya, pero entonces no hay mucha diferencia entre eso y hacerlo uno a uno, lo estás haciendo realmente igual

Comment: Eh no, porque como lo estas haciendo ahora, te da como resultado que a todos les estas asignando la misma función hola... mediante condicionales puedes asignar funciones diferentes, a cada botón.

Comment: Yo me refería a hacerlo en plan:

`f0.querySelector(".btn-event-sndFrm").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         console.log('Hola');
      });`

En vez de hacerlo por el bucle for

Comment: Ah claro, mucha diferencia no hay, ahora que son 3... puedes hacerlo uno por uno... pero recuerda que los bucles son para realizar operaciones "masivas" para evitar la sobrecarga de código. Pero en definitiva, ambas opciones son igual de válidas

Comment: Pero teniendo las dos opciones en mente, a la hora de optimizar el código ¿Cuál sería mejor, hacer las 3 asignaciones mediante el bucle for, o hacerlas manualmente?

Contando con que después quizá pueda añadir otro botón, ¿cuál seguiría siendo mejor? Estoy hablando de un formulario muy dinámico.

Comment: Siempre, siempre, siempre, siempre debes inclinarte por los bucles si necesitas realizar operaciones de ese tipo, ni siquiera lo dudes xD